# Issue with python skipping code in simple chess program

Tags: python, chess

I am creating a simple program for chess, and I ran to an issue of supposedly python skipping code.
Program entry is: find_side()

Console output:

```
Enter your team(1-black 2-white):1
<PlayResult at 0x3ec1dc0 (move=e2e4, ponder=d7d5, info={}, draw_offered=False, resigned=False)>
Enter your enemies move:
```

According to the console output, engine randomly generated move for the White player and made a counter-response in ponder. But I have input for that, looks like, that python is executing `result_engine` sooner than user input. 
Also, there's one more problem. Engine completely ignores the `chess.engine.turn = turn` line.
I am using stockfish 11 as an engine and `import chess` as an link between python code and engine with universal chess engine
Code:

```
import chess
import chess.engine
import time
import os

def logic_white():
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sf.exe")
    board = chess.Board()

    turn = True  # True - white False - black
    while True:
        chess.engine.turn = turn # This isn't working
        result_engine = engine.play(board,chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
        print(result_engine)

        res = input("Enter your enemie's move: ")
        move = chess.Move.from_uci(res)

        board.push(move)
        turn = not turn
        time.sleep(0.5)

def logic_black():
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sf.exe")
    board = chess.Board()

    turn = True # True - white False - black
    while True:
        chess.engine.turn = turn # This isn't working

        res = input("Enter your enemie's move: ")
        move = chess.Move.from_uci(res) #Inputting the enemy move and putting in on the virtual board
        board.push(move)

        result_engine = engine.play(board,chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1)) #Calculating best move to respond
        print(result_engine)
        board.push(result_engine) #Push the engine's move to the virtual board

        turn = not turn # Inverting turn, so turns can change from black to white, etc.
        time.sleep(0.5)       

def find_side():
    if(input("Enter your team(1-black 2-white):")) == 1:
        logic_black()
    else:
        logic_white()
```

Comment: looks like an interesting program, please include a running example of code that creates this issue, The code you have posted doesn't have a start point.

Comment: Basically, this is a starting point. At the end of the program, I have only a ```find_side()``` calling

Comment: Not sure what the effect of this is but you might be missing a `board.push(result_engine)` in the top `logic_white()` function.

Comment: My code is in order, that I posted here. Functions are above and calling of them is bellow. And by that fact, output is given and it is not giving any error. For example - logic_black not found, I suppose that, python see this function. And about ```board.push(result_engine)```, first move is made by white player, so I would input it first, and only then calculate next move. Putting it on the top will result in 0 or any random value from RAM being written on the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's input function returns a string, so it will never be equal to the integer 1. As such, the code will always go into the else block. To fix this, either convert the input to an integer or compare it to '1'.

```
def find_side():
    if int(input("Enter your team(1-black 2-white):")) == 1:
        logic_black()
    else:
        logic_white()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe you know a bit about chess library in python? Why turn is being ignored in the chess.engine.turn?

Comment: I was looking through the documentation and it seems like chess.engine.turn is not an attribute present in chess.engine and as such, it does not do anything. So it is not that it is being ignored. The program is assigning the value of turn into chess.engine.turn. Just that this assignment does not yield any result.